# Flask、requestsでサーバから返ってくるデータを確認するには

Tags: python, python3, flask, python-requests

pinterestのapiを使用したくアクセストークンを取得するコードを作成しています。Flaskで自身のサーバを立てており、ここにpinterestのサーバから認証コードが届きます。

アクセストークンを取得する道のりとしてhttps通信でログインした状態で認証URLにアクセスします。次にpost通信で認証を認めると設定したredirect_urlに認証コードが付与されて返ってきます。
　このコードをプログラムで取り出したいのですが、どのようにコードを作成したら良いのかわかりません。ご教授お願いします。

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    s = requests.Session()
    p = s.post(login_url, params=userdata)
    g = s.get(authorizatio_url, params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(g.text, 'lxml')
    name = soup.input.get('name')
    value = soup.input.get('value')
    authorization = {'name':'value'}
    last_access = s.post(authorizatio_url, params=authorizatio_url)
    return 'good'

@app.route('/callbackpage')
def callbackpage():
    return 'tokenget'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flaskでは、 `flask.request` を参照することでクライアントからのリクエストを参照することができます（これは、 `requests` とは異なります）。

上記のコードを元にするなら、以下のように外部からどのように認証コードが付与されているか確認して、続きを記述してみてください。

```py
import pprint
from flask import request

# 中略

@app.route('/callbackpage')
def callbackpage():
    pprint(request)
    return 'tokenget'
```

参考：

- [クイックスタート - リクエストデータへのアクセス — Flask v0.5.1 documentation](https://a2c.bitbucket.io/flask/quickstart.html#id9)
- [チュートリアル — Flask v0.5.1 documentation](https://a2c.bitbucket.io/flask/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: 無事取得できました。ありがとうございます。